# Halt JavaFX program until after Transition is complete

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, translate-animation

I am making a JavaFX program that uses multiple [`TranslateTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/TranslateTransition.html)s to move multiple [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html)s across a [`Pane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html). I want the program to halt execution until after the transitions are complete.

```java
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Stack Overflow MRE");
        Pane root = new Pane();

        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(25, 100, Color.AQUA);
        rect1.setX(10);
        rect1.setY(10);

        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(25, 100, Color.BISQUE);
        rect2.setX(465);
        rect2.setY(10);

        root.getChildren().addAll(rect1, rect2);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                TranslateTransition translateRect1 = new TranslateTransition();
                translateRect1.setNode(rect1);
                translateRect1.setAutoReverse(true);
                translateRect1.setCycleCount(1);
                translateRect1.setToY(350);
                translateRect1.setDuration(Duration.millis(5000));
                translateRect1.play();

                TranslateTransition translateRect2 = new TranslateTransition();
                translateRect2.setNode(rect2);
                translateRect2.setAutoReverse(true);
                translateRect2.setCycleCount(1);
                translateRect2.setToY(350);
                translateRect2.setDuration(Duration.millis(5000));
                translateRect2.play();
            }
            // The loop will continue iterating while the above transitions are still running
            // I need the loop to pause until they complete
            System.out.printf("The current iteration is %s\n", i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

In the above code sample, the two transitions occur simultaneously, which is what I want, however the loop continues before the transitions complete. I want the loop to pause until the transitions are complete, and then move on to the next iterations. How would I get the program to first complete the transitions before moving on to the rest of the code?

Comment: Sorry, this edit doesn't really make any sense to me. You'd never really write code like this. You would create the transitions, and then in the `onFinished` handler run the loop starting with `i=1`.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with the solution I posted. It answers your question.

Comment: It wouldn't work in my actual program, it just happens to work with the MRE that I used because it is simplified. I'm not really sure how to express what my issue is.

Comment: That just sounds like you don't properly understand the solution.

Comment: Look, I get it, I'm a beginner. I'm trying to delete the question. I might ask again when I can figure out how to write a more helpful MRE for the specific problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: I think what you're missing is that writing the loop is almost certainly the wrong approach entirely. This is UI programming: it's *event driven*. So you should always think about writing code that is invoked by the UI framework when some event happens (e.g. the user performs some action, or an animation finishes, etc.). JavaFX already implements a UI loop for you.

Comment: @James_D The purpose of the loop isn't to modify the UI. The loop is part of an algorithm that I am using elsewhere in the program. The issue is that I want it to interact with the UI, but I can't get it to pause until that interaction is complete.

Comment: Yes, I get what you're trying to do. You just need to re-imagine it as something event-driven, rather than algorithmic. Have a look at my solution to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62963502/how-do-i-update-a-xychart-in-realtime-in-java-using-javafx and see if it helps. And again, *you must not pause your loop* (unless you are going to execute it in a background thread, which makes things considerably harder).

Comment: @James_D Yes, that does help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an `onFinished` handler for the transition after which you want the code to execute, e.g.

```
    TranslateTransition translateRect2 = new TranslateTransition();
    translateRect2.setNode(rect2);
    translateRect2.setAutoReverse(true);
    translateRect2.setCycleCount(1);
    translateRect2.setToY(350);
    translateRect2.setDuration(Duration.millis(5000));

    translateRect2.setOnFinished(e -> {
        System.out.println("Testing timing of output");
    });

    translateRect2.play();

    // This line prints while the above transitions are still running
    // System.out.println("Testing timing of output");
```

The solution for your edited question is essentially the same: refactor it in the obvious way so that the code that you want to run after the transitions is in the `onFinished` handler:

```
    TranslateTransition translateRect1 = new TranslateTransition();
    translateRect1.setNode(rect1);
    translateRect1.setAutoReverse(true);
    translateRect1.setCycleCount(1);
    translateRect1.setToY(350);
    translateRect1.setDuration(Duration.millis(5000));
    translateRect1.play();

    TranslateTransition translateRect2 = new TranslateTransition();
    translateRect2.setNode(rect2);
    translateRect2.setAutoReverse(true);
    translateRect2.setCycleCount(1);
    translateRect2.setToY(350);
    translateRect2.setDuration(Duration.millis(5000));

    translateRect2.setOnFinished(e -> {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.printf("The current iteration is %s\n", i);
        }
    });

    translateRect2.play();
    System.out.printf("The current iteration is 0\n");
```

Comment: Suppose the transitions were in a loop. I would only want the loop to continue to run after the transitions were complete. What could I put in the call to `setOnFinished` to make that work?

Comment: @ap Not sure I fully understand. If you have multiple transitions that you want to run one after the other, you could put them all into a `SequentialTransition`. Or you could create the next transition in the `onFinished` handler of the previous one. But it sounds like you need to clarify your question.

Comment: I meant that the transitions are being called in a loop that also contains other code. The actual transitions themselves are in a method that is only called during a single one of the loop's iterations. I want the transitions to complete before the loop moves to the next iteration. I'm not sure how I would pause the loop using `setOnFinished`. I will edit my question momentarily with an updated MRE to clarify what I am saying.

Comment: @ap You can't "pause the loop", because it's being run on the FX Application Thread, so you'd hang the UI. It's not clear why you can't just do the same thing I've done in the answer; move the code that you want to execute after the animation to the `onFinished` handler.

Comment: The way I have it set up now, the code in each iteration occurs simultaneously. I can't move the code into the `onFinished` handler because the code only works in the context of the loop.